# Asynchronous mapping of Array elements Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an Object as follows:

```
  let  data =  {
  "requested_by": 26,
  "request_type": "regularization",
  "employee_ids": [
    26
  ],
  "request_data": [
    {
      "from_date": "2020-03-14",
      "from_time": "04:18",
      "to_time": "09:45",
      "comment": "a",
      "to_date": "2020-03-14"
    },


  ]
}
```

In this the request_data is Array of objects which can have n number of objects let's assume it is 8, Now I wanted to make chunks of it by 6 so a request_data of 6 objects and request_data of 2 objects and the other keys replicated as is. Now with these chunks i'd make two API calls so what I did was

```
  requestBatches.map((item: any) => {
          console.log(item)
          data['request_data'] = item
          console.log(data)
           requestDataChunks.push(this.createRequest({ data, files }))
        })
```

The requestBatches has an Array of two chunks of request_data key one with 6 and other with 2,
I wanted to make an API call with these two different chunks so I mapped it to the key and made push it to an array and will later use Promise.all to resolve every promise

My Problem:
Every time in this map function, I get the second chunk i.e the last element in requestBatches Array in data['request_data'] though the console.log(item) shows correct chunks
The API gets called two times which is correct but the payload data ->request_data key has the last element of requestBatches in both the request the first element is getting overwritten because of some asynchronous flow.

UPDATE:
I saw some weird behaviour after making chunks

```
 function chunkArray(myArray: Array<any>, chunk_size: number) {
      let results = []

      while (myArray.length) {
        results.push(myArray.splice(0, chunk_size))
      }

      return results
    }
```

this is the function I am using to chunk array of equal sizes and when I pass my array to this function the key in the data object request_data is also getting updated with 0 i.e after splice because of while loop why is it this reactive behaviour I tried taking another variable and then doing it but the original element still got updated

Comment: Please don't use `.map` for simple iteration.

Comment: Shall I Use forEach()?

Comment: `data['request_data'] = item` you are continually updating a single field with one item each time.  `this.createRequest({ data, files })` then using *the same* object in this call, which means that you're modifying "all" of these. Depending on what `createRequest` does, this can very well lead to a change of behaviour.

Comment: I tried commenting out that API call and had a console.log(data) there instead-but still I see two console logs for data which still has the last elements in that particular key and the first element is getting overwritten

Comment: If you want to do simple iteration, then `.forEach` or a normal loop would do. If you want to do a *mapping* operation, then follow the rules - mapping is converting `X` -> `Y` so your callback should be doing this, thus `Array<X>` if mapped through the function will produce `Array<Y>`. This is very well established terminology coming  from [mathematics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_(mathematics)) and is [used in computer science](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_(higher-order_function)). By misusing the idiom, you're making your code harder to read and understand.

Comment: Even .forEach fetches me the same result  the first chunk is lost only second chunk is getting mapped to both the data payload